# Can't build the facebook bindings

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios

I just downloaded these facebook bindings : https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook

I use "make" command from facebook/binding/ directory but i can't build Facebook.dll.Here is the error:

```
Project "/Users/abc/facebook/binding/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.csproj" (default target(s)): Target _AssignBundleResourceNames: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Xamarin.ObjcBinding.Common.targets: error : Error executing task AssignBundleResourceNames: Invalid reserved metadata name Task "AssignBundleResourceNames" execution -- FAILED Done building target "_AssignBundleResourceNames" in project "/Users/abc/facebook/binding/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.csproj".-- FAILED Done building project "/Users/abc/facebook/binding/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED. Errors:

/Users/abc/facebook/binding/MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.csproj (default targets) -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Xamarin.ObjcBinding.Common.targets (_AssignBundleResourceNames target) ->

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Xamarin.ObjcBinding.Common.targets: error : Error executing task AssignBundleResourceNames: Invalid reserved metadata name
```

Comment: What version of Xamarin.iOS are you running?

Comment: My version is 6.2.4.2.It's the latest stable version.

Comment: Please try `make prepare` and then try to open `MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.csproj` with Xamarin Studio and build from there

Comment: Thank you! "make prepare" then "sudo make" worked for me.